# Different outputs when using break in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wrote a simple script:

```
for DIR in /etc/*; do
    if [ "$DIR" == "/etc/dhcp" ]; then
        echo $DIR
        break
    fi
done
```

This works correctly but if I use `break` after `fi` it doesn't generate the desirable result.

What is the difference between that script and this one?

```
for DIR in /etc/*; do
    if [ "$DIR" == "/etc/dhcp" ]; then
        echo $DIR
    fi
    break
done
```

Comment: I edited your post and added some indentation. Feel free to revert it if you don't like it. But to my mind it is now clearer that in the second case the `break` is _outside_ the `if`.

Comment: @PerlDuck and that's why indentation is important. :P

Comment: What were the different outputs? And what were the inputs? Ah well, I suppose it doesn't really matter, maybe the title could be better

Answer (score 6):

In simple terms, if the condition is met, the `for` loop will be terminated in the first script. But in the second script, the `for` loop will terminate irrespective of whether the condition is met or not. That `for` loop will be executed once. So, there is no benefit of a for loop in the second script since the results would be the same.

So, at the end of the first script, the value of `DIR` will be `/etc/dhcp` and an output will be there. But in the case of the second script, the value of `DIR` will be the name of the folder found at first. It may happen that it is `/etc/dhcp`. In that case the if condition will be executed and you'll see an output. But if the value of `DIR` is something else, then there will be no output.